# Using variable in jstl "key" of <fmt:message key="<%=customFieldData%>" />

Tags: jsp, jstl

In my jsp page there are some labels coming from controller in spring mvc. But I am trying to use a properties file to show a different values for those labels. Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:bundle basename="main.resources.abc_messages">
                <%
                    if (request.getAttribute("customFields") != null) {
                        String line = request.getAttribute("customFields").toString();
                        line = line.subSequence(1, line.length() - 1).toString();
                        String[] data = splitLineIntoArray(line, ",");
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            String field = data[i];
                            String[] customFieldData = splitLineIntoArray(field, "=");
                %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left">
                    <fmt:message key="<%=customFieldData[0]%>"/>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <input type="text" type="customField"
                            value="<%=customFieldData[1]%>" id="customField"
                            class="inputfixed" disabled="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <%
                    }
                    }
                %>
</fmt:bundle>
```

I have put properties file abc_messages.properties in the classpath. When I use key="abc" and the properties file has abc=xyz then I get the value xyz. But on using the variable as required here I get ???.

But I am always getting this as output

```
??? color???   : green
??? font ???   : arial
```

abc_messages.properties file

```
color=Main Color
font=Main Font
```

Comment: Are you using maven when you are building and that is why you have your property files in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Yes its a maven project. resources folder is in the classpath. But I have also tried by putting the same properties file in root folder and changing <fmt:bundle basename="main.resources.abc_messages"> to <fmt:bundle basename="abc_messages"> . But it gave the same output

Comment: Actually given that setup `<fmt:bundle basename="abc_messages">` is what should work. This may be a long shot, have you tried without the underscore in the file name? Also have you tried to hard code the properties in your `fmt:message` tags to see if there is something wrong there?

Comment: I have tried without underscore but same result. In the properties file I added abc=xyz   and in jsp   <fmt:bundle basename="main.resources.blueawaremessages">
<fmt:message key="abc"/></fmt:bundle>     But still getting ???abc???

Comment: Remove the `main.resources.` part. Unless you actually have it in a `src/main/resources/main/resources` folder, that shouldn't be there. Have you verified that your property file indeed ends up in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder? Do you have other language property files for the same `ResourceBundle`?

Comment: Yesterday I identified the issue. The problem is not with the classpath. <fmt:message key="abc"/></fmt:bundle> But still getting ???abc??? was because I was adding abc=xyz in the wrong properties file (the one placed in the root). Sorry for that. The problem is with the variable that I am using in the key. If I use <fmt:message key="abc"/></fmt:bundle> I gat the proper value "xyz"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help @DanielBarbarian. I am getting the expected result now. The issue was with an extra space that I was getting as CustomFields data. " color " was the string I was getting but in properties file there was "color". So it gave ??? color ??? . I should have trim() the customFieldData before putting in key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with an extra space that I was getting as CustomFields data. " color " was the string I was getting but in properties file there was "color". So it gave ??? color ??? . I should have trim() the customFieldData before putting in key